# Kitchen Faucet vibrates and leaks when you take a shower upstairs

Tags: plumbing, faucet, leaking

This problem happens frequently, but not all the time.  You can be taking a shower upstairs and downstairs in the kitchen the cold water faucet vibrates violently and loudly and spits out water by itself (the valve is closed and no one is even near it).  Any ideas?

Comment: Resonant frequency is setting up a standing vibration which has pressure pulses. Could be a water hammer arrestor on the kitchen cold supply would stop it. If you run the cold water in the shower at a higher flow rate the oscillation might go away. Try experimenting with running the shower cold only at various flow rates. If this works to alleviate the oscillation, then raise the temp of the hot water so you can shower with a higher flow rate of the cold.

Comment: Another possible remedy to try would be to turn the lavarory faucet on cold at a moderate flow and leave it on while showering. This might stop the pulsating, if it responds to lhigher flow rate of cold water,

Comment: Ahh.  thank you for that thought.  It sounds like it is the mixture / flow rate of the cold to hot.  I had a couple of weeks ago lowered the tankless hot water temp from 120 to 115.  which would lower the mixture rate.  the showers are a single mixed valve.  based on your idea, i just raised the tankless temperature back up to 120.  my wife just mentioned the only other time this seems to happen is when she ran the laundry machine (which also automatically mixes the water to temp).  fingers crossed this might solve the issue.  will let you know.  thank you!

Comment: We had a utility sink added in the garage. The water supply is from tapping into the lines for a bathroom lavatory on the other side of the wall. For some reason the hot supply screeches and pulsates at low to low moderate flow rates. Higher flow rates are no drama.